# Connect google cloud function to an oracle database

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Does anyone know, how to connect google cloud function(Python) to an Oracle database ? I tried importing cx_Oracle library in cloud function. But it shows an error

> *Function load error: DPI-1047: Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file*

Following is main.py code:

```
import cx_Oracle

def import_data(request):

    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request_json and 'message' in request_json:
        con = cx_Oracle.connect("username", "password", "host:port/SID")
        print(con.version)
        con.close
```

Following is requirement.txt

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version
cx_Oracle==6.0b1
```

Comment: You need to provide more information than this.  Please give us some sample code

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli i updated question with code snippets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems Google Cloud Functions [does not support shared libraries](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/112809590) (in other words, it only supports "pure python" libraries) and that cx_oracle depends on this. Sadly I haven't been able to find a pure-python Oracle library, so for now this is not supported.

Your best bet is to use App Engine Flexible as it the closest equivalent service that [allows non-pure python libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-python-libraries). cl_oracle should work with it.

Comment: While `sqlplus_commando` is in itself pure-python, it depends on having `sqlplus` installed, which I don't think is possible on GCF. To connect to Oracle SqlAlchemy depends on cx_oracle, so again I don't think it'll work.

Comment: I've added a suggestion to use GAE Flex to my answer, as that should allow cx_oracle.

Comment: yes i agree with your answer regarding sqlplus_commando and sqlALchemy . Thank you